# django-tastypie : Related data not saving

Tags: python, django, api, rest, tastypie

My `models.py`

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=7, primary_key=True)
    users = models.ForeignKey(ProductUsers, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    address = models.ForeignKey(ProductUsersAddress, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    payment_method = models.CharField(default='COD', max_length=20, choices=PAYMENT_METHOD)

class OrderedProduct(models.Model):
    products = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    orders = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=False)
```

My `resources.py`

```
class OrdersResource(ModelResource):

    ordered_products = fields.ToManyField('orders.resources.OrderedProductResource',
                                          attribute=lambda bundle: OrderedProduct.objects.filter(orders=bundle.obj),
                                          related_name='orders', full=True, null=True)

    contact_no = fields.ForeignKey(ProductUsersResource, 'users')
    address = fields.ForeignKey(ProductUsersAddressResource, 'address')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Orders.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'orders'
        include_resource_uri = False
        collection_name = 'orders'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        always_return_data = True

class OrderedProductResource(ModelResource):
    products = fields.ForeignKey(ProductsResource, 'products')
    orders = fields.ForeignKey(OrdersResource, 'orders')

    class Meta:
        queryset = OrderedProduct.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'ordered_products'
        excludes = ['id']
        include_resource_uri = False
```

I entered data using Django-Admin.
When I hit, `http://localhost:8000/orders/`, I get,

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "address": "/api/v1/address/1",
      "contact_no": "/api/v1/users/8269661606",
      "order_id": "KJLSWI",
      "ordered_products": [
        {
          "orders": "/api/v1/orders/KJLSWI",
          "price": "40.00",
          "products": "/api/v1/products/1",
          "quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "orders": "/api/v1/orders/KJLSWI",
          "price": "70.00",
          "products": "/api/v1/products/2",
          "quantity": 4
        },
        {
          "orders": "/api/v1/orders/KJLSWI",
          "price": "67.00",
          "products": "/api/v1/products/3",
          "quantity": 7
        }
      ],
      "payment_method": "COD",
    }
  ]
}
```

Now according to tasty documentation,

> Tastypie encourages “round-trippable” data, which means the data you
>   can GET should be able to be POST/PUT’d back to recreate the same
>   object.
>   If you’re ever in question about what you should send, do a GET on
>   another object & see what Tastypie thinks it should look like.

But when I post same data by just changing primary-key,

```
{
  "address": "/api/v1/address/1",
  "contact_no": "/api/v1/users/8269661606",
  "order_id": "ABCDE",
  "ordered_products": [
    {
      "orders": "/api/v1/orders/ABCDE",
      "price": "40.00",
      "products": "/api/v1/products/1",
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "orders": "/api/v1/orders/ABCDE",
      "price": "70.00",
      "products": "/api/v1/products/2",
      "quantity": 4
    },
    {
      "orders": "/api/v1/orders/ABCDE",
      "price": "67.00",
      "products": "/api/v1/products/3",
      "quantity": 7
    }
  ],
  "payment_method": "COD",
}
```

I get response,

```
{
  "address": "/api/v1/address/1",
  "contact_no": "/api/v1/users/8269661606",
  "ordered_products": [],
  "payment_method": "COD",
}
```

My data in model `OrderedProduct`, is not getting saved. WHYYYYYYY ??????

Comment: Have you verified on django shell and query for all objects before and after your post? What do you see?

Comment: @ShangWang Yes, I did.. data gets saved in 'Orders' table but not in 'OrderedProduct'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760973/posting-data-to-create-related-tastypie-resources-simultaneously

Comment: I know, i have to do something with related_name, I tried almost every possible way, but its not working for me. I added related _name to my ToManyField. But still result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def hydrate_m2m(self, bundle):
    for ordered_product in bundle.data['ordered_products']:
        if isinstance(ordered_product, dict):
            ordered_product.update({'orders': bundle.obj})

    return super(OrdersResource, self).hydrate_m2m(bundle)
```

and remove `orders` key from `ordered_products` JSON

and replace `attribute=lambda bundle: OrderedProduct.objects.filter(orders=bundle.obj)` with `orders`

and move `related_name='orders'` from resource to model.

Finally:

model:

```
class OrderedProduct(models.Model):
    products = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    orders = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=False)
```

resource:

```
class OrdersResource(ModelResource):

    ordered_products = fields.ToManyField('orders.resources.OrderedProductResource',
                                          'orders', full=True, null=True)

    contact_no = fields.ForeignKey(ProductUsersResource, 'users')
    address = fields.ForeignKey(ProductUsersAddressResource, 'address')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Orders.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'orders'
        include_resource_uri = False
        collection_name = 'orders'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        always_return_data = True

    def hydrate_m2m(self, bundle):
        for ordered_product in bundle.data['ordered_products']:
            if isinstance(ordered_product, dict):
                ordered_product.update({'orders': bundle.obj})

        return super(OrdersResource, self).hydrate_m2m(bundle)
```

and POST data:

```
{
  "address": "/api/v1/address/1",
  "contact_no": "/api/v1/users/8269661606",
  "order_id": "ABCDE",
  "ordered_products": [
    {
      "price": "40.00",
      "products": "/api/v1/products/1",
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "price": "70.00",
      "products": "/api/v1/products/2",
      "quantity": 4
    },
    {
      "price": "67.00",
      "products": "/api/v1/products/3",
      "quantity": 7
    }
  ],
  "payment_method": "COD",
}
```

Comment: Adding 'orders' to every ordered_product like you did it in `hydrate_m2m`, if I do it in `alter_deserialized_detail_data` will it be any bad ? It can be stupid question, I am a beginner to django, please consider it. :)

Comment: In this case You need `bundle.obj`. In `alter_deserialized_detail_data` You do not have it. In `hydrate_m2m` You have it.

Comment: Is there any way, I can do same for `address`, `contact_no` and `products` as well ? Like not adding `/api/v1/resource_name` in post data, but adding them using tastypie.